# Synchronisation in a Multi-Threaded C++11 application

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, server

I work on a multi-threaded Server application written in C++ and executed on a embedded Linux. One Thread (I call them Communication-Thread) should handle all socket I/Os (send and receive message).
Dependent on the received message, the Communication-Thread send the message to another Thread (e.g. Controller-Thread) which handle the required sequence. A return message is created at the end of the sequence by the Controller-Thread. This message is written back to the Communication-Thread, which should transfer them to the client.

The Communication between this two threads is implemented with Queues which are protected through *mutex* and *condition_variable*. Now when the Communication-Thread received a socket message, it transfer them to the Controller-Thread and wait for a message from the Controller-Thread. 
So no benefit is given through the multi-threaded architecture. My goal is to wait in the Communication-Thread for a socket message OR a 'queued' message.

For that I thinking to change the queue implementation between the Threads and replace them with a pipe or a eventfd. Then I would use the select() function in the Communication-Thread to observe the queue and socket simultaneously. But I have some concerns about the performance of this solution. 
Has someone a better idea or solution for this problem?

**Compact question:**

I would observe a socket and some kind of messages in a multi-threaded application, simultaneously.
Do some one know a more efficient implementation than pipes or eventfd for this type of problem?

Thanks for any hint on this topic

Answer (score 2):

Use boost::asio, if it is available on your embedded Linux version. It is designed to do exactly what you want, has a great interface and really good functionality. Have a look at the tutorials. It takes a little getting used to, but it makes multithreaded networking applications a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for your hint to boos::asio. Right now, I haven't the boost library on my embedded device. So I keep them in my mind. I did the stride forward implementation with eventfd. It seams to be enough efficient for the synchronization...